# Showing that, in general, the altitudes of a tetrahedron don't meet.

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to solve a problem but I think I'm lost.

At first, they tell us that an altitude, or height, or well, I don't know how to call it sorry I have the problem in another language, okay, so that, the height of a tetrahedron it's a line which passes through a vertex and it's perpendicular to the plane determined by the other three vertices.

> I have to show that, in general, the altitudes of a tetrahedron don't meet.

Could you help me, please? I don't know how to start. Should I try to think of an example that doesn't match the definition?

I hope that you understood my translation of the problem.

Thanks

Edit:
I've found a version of the exercise in English and it's probably better than my translation. So it says:

A tetrahedron in a Euclidean affine space of dimension 3 is a set of four affinely independent points. An altitude of a tetrahedron is a line passing through
one vertex and perpendicular to the plane determined by the other three vertices.

Prove by means of an example that a pair of altitudes of a tetrahedron need not intersect.

Comment: Are you treating tetrahedra in general—that is, not necessarily regular tetrahedra? ¶ It might be useful if you appended the problem in the original language.

Comment: Don't know how to do that but it's in Catalan.... And doesn't say anythin about regular or not, so I guess that all of them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_tetrahedron

Comment: "Need not interact" means that you need to find at least one example. The tetrahedron can has 6 edges. Construct the tetrahedron with different edges.